2-Dimension Random Walk Boundary Problem
I am working on this problem that is analogous to the Gambler's ruin problem in 2-dimensions. More motivation of boundary problems of 2-dimensional random walk can be found in this thesis.
We have a discrete two-dimensional random walk that moves one unit in four directions (up, down, right, left) each with equal probability of $\frac{1}{4}$. Starting at an arbitrary point $(x_0,y_0)$, what is the probability of the process hitting the x-axis before hitting the y-axis? Is there a closed-form solution?
